# Create a list with specific string length from another list

Tags: python

Apologies for any confusion in the explanation below, but I'm a little new to Python.

I have a list of text, and I would like to chunk the list up into larger pieces based on a separate list of values.

**For example:**

```
lst_a = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'a', 'simple', 'English', 'sentence.']
lst_b = [3, 4, 2]
```

**Desired Result:**

```
new_lst_a = ['This is an', 'example of a simple', 'English sentence.']
```

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please post your attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this using **[slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)**:

```
lst_a = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'a', 'simple', 'English', 'sentence.']
lst_b = [3, 4, 2]
new_list = []

index = 0
for n in lst_b:
    new_list.append(' '.join(lst_a[index:index + n]))
    index += n

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['This is an', 'example of a simple', 'English sentence.']
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this produced the results I was needing!

Answer (score 2):

If you write a simple for-loop you can consume an iterator of the original list. This approach makes no unnecessary copies.

```
>>> result = []
>>> it = iter(lst_a)
>>> for n in lst_b:
...     s = " ".join(next(it) for i in range(n))
...     result.append(s)
...
>>> result
['This is an', 'example of a simple', 'English sentence.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `islice` to do this easily by grabbing n elements at a time

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> lst_a = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'a', 'simple', 'English', 'sentence.']
>>> lst_b = [3, 4, 2]
>>> 
>>> itr = iter(lst_a)
>>> [' '.join(islice(itr, n)) for n in lst_b]
['This is an', 'example of a simple', 'English sentence.']
```